# How to start using redis in .net

Tags: asp.net, redis

I'm new in NO-SQL concept and I want to start using redis in Asp.net web apps. Through my search ,I couldn't find the good example of using Redis with Asp.net with explanation of redis details for beginners ,any help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [**ServiceStack.Redis**](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) for that and a here is a good tutorial for it [**Getting started with Redis in ASP.NET under Windows**](http://maxivak.com/getting-started-with-redis-and-asp-net-mvc-under-windows/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ,seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

if you wana use redis in your Asp.net application you have two way for using Redis:

1.using Redis with Adding  DistributedRedisCache into your startup class.

2.using third party library like **serviceStack.Redis or** **StackExchange.Redis** !

I told you a series of general explanations and now it is time to coding with Redis !!!

**First approach:**

first of all you should install below package in your pplication :

**Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core**

after that add below section into you appsetting.json file:

```
 "redis": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 6379,
    "name": "localhost"
  }
```

and now it is time to add installed package to your starup as service:

```
 services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.InstanceName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:name");
                options.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:host");
            });
```

now you can use Redis in your application :

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
        public HomeController(IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string data = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cache.GetString("Student")))
            {
                _cache.SetString("student", "hamidhasani");
            }
            else
            {
                data = _cache.GetString("student");
            }
            ViewData["DistCache"] = data;
            return View(data);
        }
}
```

**Second Approach:**

in this approach should install a libary and here i want to install service stack so lets  add it into our project :

install-package serviceStack.Redis

after this it is time to use it .i expose the usage of that here :

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
         private IRedisClient _redisClient;
        public HomeController()
        {
             _redisClient = new RedisClient();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Person person = null;
            var NewPerson = new Person()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "hamid",
                LastName = "hasani"
            };
            var rc = _redisClient.As<Person>();
            if (rc.GetById(NewPerson.Id) == null)
            {
               person= rc.Store(person);
            }
            else
            {
              person= rc.GetById(NewPerson.Id);
            }
             return View(person);
        }
}
```